# The myLabel outlet from the UICollectionView to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I coded my first CollectionView but the build fails with this error message:

"Illegal Configuration: The myLabel outlet from the UICollectionView to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

I read other questions on StackOverflow with the same error, and the solution was to set the content of the UILabel which is in a prototype cell and has an outlet to "CollectionViewCell.swift" from static to dynamic. I couldn't try this because this option doesn't appear. I think it's gone with the newer versions of Xcode.

My code in "CollectionViewCell.swift":

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
}
```

My code in "ViewController.swift":

```
class LibraryViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var sortCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    func numberOfSections(in sortCollectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ sortCollectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ sortCollectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let sortCell = sortCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sortCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        sortCell.myLabel.text = "hi"
        return sortCell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Thank you for every helpful answer :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your UILabel from Storyboard and check connections of it, there might be an old connection of it. Remove that old connection and you are good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it by myself!
For everyone who search for the solution:
Double check if there are no other Outlets than the CollectionViewCell!
In my case the Label had an outlet to another thing :^)

Comment: Thats Great, (Y).